# form post not posting hidden field because of action?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="https://www.example.com/product_info.php?action=add_product" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(); ">
<input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="226" />      
<input type="hidden" name="final_sale" value="final_sale" />
</form>
```

The products_id is properly being passed to the shopping cart page. However the final sale value I am trying to add is not.

The form action functions:

```
$goto =  shopping_cart.php;
        $parameters = array('action', 'cPath', 'products_id', 'pid');

case 'add_product' :    if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id']) && is_numeric($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'])) {
    $attributes = isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['id']) ? $HTTP_POST_VARS['id'] : '';

    $cart->add_cart($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $cart->get_quantity(tep_get_uprid($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $HTTP_POST_VARS['id'])) + $HTTP_POST_VARS['cart_quantity'], $HTTP_POST_VARS['id']);


}
    tep_redirect(tep_href_link($goto, tep_get_all_get_params($parameters)));
    break;
```

I tried changing the action to include the final_sale value (which I didnt think was necessary):

```
case 'add_product' :    if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id']) && is_numeric($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'])) {
            $attributes = isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['id']) ? $HTTP_POST_VARS['id'] : '';
            $final_sale = isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['final_sale']) ? $HTTP_POST_VARS['final_sale'] : '';
            $cart->add_cart($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $cart->get_quantity(tep_get_uprid($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id'], $HTTP_POST_VARS['id'])) + $HTTP_POST_VARS['cart_quantity'], $HTTP_POST_VARS['id']);


        }
            tep_redirect(tep_href_link($goto, tep_get_all_get_params($parameters)));
            break;
```

This too did not work.

In shopping_cart.php I am just trying to echo the value like so to see if it passes but I am getting nothing:

```
echo $_GET['final_sale'];

if (tep_not_null( ($_GET['final_sale']) )) {
    echo "finalsale";

}
```

Comment: `echo $_GET['final_sale'];` should be `echo $_POST['final_sale'];`. (because you've set the method of the form to POST). And in the snipped above I can't see where you would use `$final_sale` at all!?

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with code samples you provided:

1. Variable `$HTTP_POST_VARS` isn't [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) so to use it you need to declare it using a [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword.
2. Also the `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is depreceted and you should use the `$_POST` variable insetead. The `$_POST` is superglobal so you don't need to use the `global` keyword.
3. In last code sample you used `$_GET` variable but form which you created is declared as `POST`.

To make your code work you need replace all `$HTTP_POST_VARS` and `$_GET` variables to `$_POST`.

Comment: I updated the deprecated HTTP_POST_VARS to _$POST and I changed the _$GET to echo _$POST but I am still not getting the value to echo. I actually removed the $POST in the action function because I don't think I need it? I should simply be able to echo the posted value on the shopping_cart page without it no? 

Checking if it isset on the shopping page though reveals that it is not, so it is for some reason not passing to shopping_cart.